# Using vba functions in cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

I need to round two values and sum them then. The problem is, I have **Czech version of MS Excel**, and rounding function is called "**Zaokrouhlit**"

[image]

So my formula looks like `=ZAOKROUHLIT(A1, 2) + ZAOKROUHLIT(A2, 2)`

Now I'm thinking, what if I send my file to someone that is using excel in different language version, will it work?

So I tried *default* function `=ROUND(A1, 2) + ROUND(A2, 2)`

[image]

But my version of excel doesn't know anything about such a function.

Fortunatelly, I can use this function inside VBA subroutines, so my question is:
**How to use VBA function inside formula?**

Comment: If you try changing your system locale does your computer recognize the English function names?  Just a guess, might not work but worth a shot.

Comment: This is not a real solution. If I send the file to somebody I would have to expect (ask) them to have the "right" system locale set in their computer too.

Comment: in my opinion it will work for all formulas which you already have in your sheets. For those which you would like to apply (on other computer) from VBA use `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` and avoid using `.FormulaLocal` or `.FormulaR1C1Local` properties in your subroutines.

Comment: @Buksy I was not proposing a solution, I was simply trying to get to the root of the problem. There are likely ways around this just like there are ways around problems inherent to conflicting international date formats, etc.

Answer (score 2):

try these localization solutions:

[VanTed Bits: Excel VBA Tip: translate formulas between local language and English](http://vantedbits.blogspot.nl/2010/10/excel-vba-tip-translate-formulas.html)

[excel-macro-inserting-internationally-valid-formula-during-run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247771/excel-macro-inserting-internationally-valid-formula-during-run-time)

there are several answers, and between them they should help you

Comment: I have not had to deal with situations like this; the links are very helpful. I think they should help OP solve the problem.