# Multilanguage excel format conditions formula in c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

It's my first question here so I hope I'm doing everything ok.

I'm trying to apply some format (background color, for example) to the even or odd rows of an excel range. I'm trying to use the [FormatCondition.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff590906.aspx) method.

The problem is that the application must work in diferent excel languages (like spanish). And when I use the formula `=MOD(ROW(),2)` in the Add method to apply the format only to even or odd rows it throws me an argument exception. Here in spanish:

> System.ArgumentException: El valor no está dentro del intervalo
>   esperado.

And here my best translation of the exception:

> System.ArgumentException: The value isn't between the expected
>   interval.

The problem seems to be the `,` character in the formula. If I use `;` the exception disappears, but then excel doesn't translate the formula so when I open the excel file in spanish the conditional format doesn't work. I must use the spanish version of the formula `=RESIDUO(FILA();2)` but that won't work in english. And if a put the formula in some randome cell it works well (so I suppose the formula isn't wrong):

```
excelSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "=MOD(ROW(),2)";
```

**My question is: How can I use multilanguage formula in FormatConditions.Add method?**

My code looks like this:

```
excelRange = excelRange.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,
                                             Formula1: "=MOD(ROW(),2)=" + par);
```

"par" is a variable to distinguish between even or odd.

I've tried changing the thread culture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo before = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                excelRange = excelRange.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1: "=MOD(ROW(),2)=" + par);
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = before;
            }
```

and using the [Type.InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3dhzwy.aspx) method to define the culture info:

```
Excel.FormatConditions aux = excelRange.FormatConditions;
Object[] args = { Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, "=MOD(ROW(),2)=" + par };
excelRange = aux.GetType().InvokeMember("Add",
                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public,
                                         null,
                                         aux,
                                         args,
                                         culture: new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

But the result is the same always.

If you have some clue to help me it'll be very appreciated. Thanks to all.

P.S: Sorry for my english, I hope I've explained it not too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution (not the best solution I think, but anyway...).I took the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247771/excel-macro-inserting-internationally-valid-formula-during-run-time)

The basic idea is to use a single cell to put the formula in English and then get the translated formula from the `Range.FormulaLocal` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff838851.aspx):

```
Excel.Range temp = excelSheet.get_Range("a1");
dynamic tempValue = temp.Value2;
temp.Formula = "=MOD(ROW(),2)=" + par;
String formula = temp.FormulaLocal;
temp.Formula = "";
temp.Value2 = tempValue;
excelRange = excelRange.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1: formula);
```

I hope this can help someone in the future.

Comment: Thank you for this!
I had the same problem, it is really inconsistent and stupid that for conditional formulas and data validation, the local format must be used.