# Different languages issue when inserting formula from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, regional-settings

do I understand correctly, that if I use a command like

```
Set myRange.formula = “=ROW(mySheet!R12)”
```

my macro will cause `#NAME?` error appear in cells if it is run on, say, Russian Excel.
I mean that in this case the above formula should be hard-coded like

```
Set myRange.formula = “=СТРОКА(mySheet!R12)”
```

where СТРОКА is the Russian analogue of the SUM function. I wouldn't anticipate Excel to be smart enough to translate the formulas in run-time. 
So is there any way around this and, most importantly, what is the most generic code to make the macro work correctly irrespective of languange ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

VBA is very EN-US-centric. VBA's [.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) and [.FormulaR1C1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx) expect the [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D). To use regional language function 'flavors' like [СТРОКА](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%90-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) then the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) or [Range.FormulaR1C1Local property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838568.aspx) should be employed instead.

The same holds true for list separator characters. Use a comma (e.g. `,`) to separate the arguments in a function when using .Formula or .FormulaR1C1 regardless of system regional settings. If your system uses a semi-colon (e.g. `;`) as the list separator character, this should only be used with .FormulaLocal or .FormulaR1C1Local.

The result on the worksheet will properly reflect the language settings of the Office installation.

```
myRange.Formula = "=ROW(mySheet!$12:$12)"
myRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW(mySheet!R12)"
myRange.FormulaLocal  = "=СТРОКА(mySheet!$12:$12)"
myRange.FormulaR1C1Local= "=СТРОКА(mySheet!R12)"
```

Comment: So, do I understand you correctly, that using .FormulaLocal will make my code absolutely viable and not dependent on the languange system ?

Comment: Then why do we need the method .Formula whatsoever ?)) And why don't they just integrate the funcionality of .FormulaLocal into the method .Formula ?)) Strange enough

Comment: Yes, it should. All that is necessary would be to make sure that you are using either [.FormulaLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) or [.FormulaR1C1Local](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838568.aspx) appropriately. The `R12` reference in your sample was a little ambiguous; I hope I guessed correctly. Also, any quotes within the formula need to be doubled up as they are going to be within a quoted string. e.g. `="abc"` becomes `.FormulaLocal = "=""abc"""`.

Comment: Formula Local is a relatively new addition. The VBA command interpreter had to be rewritten to accept language specific functions.

Comment: ok. Just to confirm - Set myRange.FormulaLocal = "=ROW(mySheet!$12:$12)" will work on all systems.

Comment: Not if your Office installation is RU-RU or anything but EN-US. However, `myRange.Formula = "=ROW(mySheet!$12:$12)"` **will** work on any system. (do not use `Set` to assign a formula)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I have struggled a lot with not get it to work with `Formula`. I have totally missed that it should be `","` instead of `";"`. I usually look in VBA debugger for values, but not in a thousand years I could have imagine that Microsoft have this difference between `Formula` and `FormulaLocal`. I know they are strange, but this strange...