# Copy Index formular in cell with row,column format

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy, cell

I try to copy a Formular to a cell. The Lookup-Value of the  `INDEX(MATCH)`function musst be dynamik. I already wrote a working code that give me the required rownumber and I have a fix columnumber.

```
Cells(findrow, 6) = "=INDEX(C:C;MATCH(" & Cells(findrow, 16) & ";DD;0))"
```

Unfortunately It doesn´t paste the formular in the Cell I want.

This doesn´t work either

```
Cells(findrow, 6).Formular = "=INDEX(C:C;MATCH(" & Cells(findrow, 16) & ";DD;0))"
```

`findrow` contains the correct row.

Does anyone has an idea, what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```vb
Cells(findrow, 6).Formula = "=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(P" & findrow & ",D:D,0))
```

The issues:

- Use `.Formula`, not `.Formular` (?).
- When using `.Formula`, you need to use a comma `,` as the separator, not `;`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724156/different-languages-issue-when-inserting-formula-from-vba) for more detail.
- You forgot to include the `:` in the `D:D`.
- `& Cells(findrow, 16) &`  is implictly attempting to concatenate the *value* of that cell when you just need its address. Since all you need is the address and you have a fixed column, you can hard-code the column letter and just concatenate `findrow`: `"...MATCH(P" & findrow & ...`

Comment: It inserts the formula now, but the lookup value needs to be cell R100 and it´s just 100 with your solution. I  need to address the last cell in the row I stored in ```findrow```

Comment: You have a hard-coded `16` in your question - that is column `P`, which I've hard-coded in the formula: `"=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(P"`... Where are you getting `R` from? If you need `R`, just change the `P` to `R`. But it's most certainly not true that "it's just 100."