# HRESULT: 0x800A03EC at implementing a formula

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to add a formula to a cell in excel via powershell but get an error

```
HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

I tried a lot of things including setting calculations to manual ($Excel.Calculation = -4153)
but still get the same result.
maybe I'm overlooking things or thinking to hard.
Does somebody can help me whit this?

```
$i = 8
[String]$formula = "=IF(D$i>0;(I$i+L$i+Z$i+AA$i+J$i+K$i)/D$i;0)" 
$Excel_ws.Cells.Item( $i , 15 ).formula =  $formula
```

Comment: that was totaly the thing in this case.....
adding the formula whit a separator , instead of ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724156/different-languages-issue-when-inserting-formula-from-vba):

- If you are using `.formula`, then the formula separator should be `,` and not `;`

  ```
  "=IF(D$i>0,(I$i+L$i+Z$i+AA$i+J$i+K$i)/D$i,0)"
  ```
- Otherwise, you can keep the `;` and use `.formulalocal` instead of `.formula`.

Comment: that was totaly the thing in this case..... adding the formula whit a separator , instead of ;