# Converting Excel formula to different locale/language

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-formula, office-interop

Let's say I have a `string` representing a formula which is valid in a German `Excel` (only):

```
=SUMME(B1; C1)
```

Is there a way I can translate formulas like this one to the current locale of Excel (or any language of choice) assuming the input formula is in a clearly defined language like e.g. German using C# code? The expected output for English would be:

```
=SUM(B1, C1)
```

As you can see, it mostly comes down to replacing the function names/keywords with their translated counterparts but this probably requires some formula parsing to be perfect.

Note that under the hood Excel stores formulas language independently already. The same Excel sheet can be opened and edited in any language. The catch is, inputting formulas has to be in the current language or it will be invalid (!). There is no such thing as a universal formula which can be pasted into any language Excel and it will work exactly the same. Not even when they're written in English.

I do not need something like an "Excel formula to C# code converter" but a means of taking the current formula language, target language and formula as input and produces the valid target language formula.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247771/excel-macro-inserting-internationally-valid-formula-during-run-time) is a similar question but using VBA code.

Comment: I'm not sure how German excel formulas work, but in English `=SUM(B1; C1)` is invalid. You can use `,` for a list or `:` for a range.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit not in all English.  Some use `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit: Yes, in German it would be exactly the following: `=SUMME(B1; C1)`. In English US it's `=SUM(B1, C1)`, my bad: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUM-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89

Comment: Have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/955662/switch-calc-or-excel-formulas-to-english-language

Comment: I think the easiest workaround is to use one computer in German and one computer in English. And make sure that you are using excel formulas i\on both systems. After a couple of months, you'll find that it becomes easier to translate the functions yourself.

Comment: And whenever you've got a formula problem for which you cannot google an answer in German: Simply send the excel file (minus all sensitive data, of course) to the other computer, solve the problem there (using English formulas), and send the excel file back to the german computer. That's how I finally managed to learn the dutch excel formulas ...

Comment: fwiw, VBA is very en-us-centric and any range.formula must be in en-us regional language. In fact, in order to use a different regional system's native functions, you assign to the range.formulalocal property instead.

Comment: If you use VBA to create your formulas then you would use the english version and on the sheet it would appear as the current locale version.  Edit - @Jeeped beat me to it...

Comment: fwiw², VBA also requires a comma as the list or parameter separator character regardless of whether the system's regional setting is a comma or a semi-colon.