# Excel VBA conditional formatting based on another column and cell value

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have looked over this forum, but I don't seem to find an answer to my question.

I have a dynamic range, based on the amount of columns and rows and want to format the cells according to different rules. However, I don't seem to be able to do so.

The range that needs to be formatted starts at K5 and is dynamic

Conditions:

1. Value of cell > 0
2. Value of row in column C = "BAU"

Whenever I run my code, I get an error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument. Here is my code:

```
Sub FormatAuswertung()

Dim last_row As Long, last_column As Long
Dim rngBlue As Range
Dim conditionBlue1 As FormatCondition

last_row = Worksheets("Auswertung2").Cells(rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
last_column = Worksheets("Auswertung2").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rngBlue = Range("K5", Cells(last_row, last_column))
Set conditionBlue1 = rngBlue.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlFormula, "=AND($C5=""BAU"",K5>0)")

With conditionBlue1
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
End With

End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Side note: you're missing the `Column` on the end of the `last_column = ...` line. Main note: what language is your Excel installation in? And which line throws the error?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yeah made a mistake when copying my code! My excel is german but to programm in VBA I need to type in English (and use the english notation). ```Set conditionBlue1 = ...``` line throws the error

Comment: Well this works perfectly for me (English-install). That suggests that `"=AND($C5=""BAU"",K5>0)"` needs changed. What does the macro recorder return if you record adding the conditional format manually?

Comment: Yes I changed it to the german version ```"=UND($C5=""BAU"";K5>0)"``` it works. This is very strange from Excel. Because when I want to insert a formula into a cell with VBA, I need to write the english version an VBA translates it into german. Seems to not do it for conditional formatting... But thans a lot @BigBen! :)

Comment: Side note: you can use `.FormulaLocal` (or `.Formula2Local` in Excel 365) to insert a formula in your local notation into a cell, without translating to the English version.

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247771/excel-macro-inserting-internationally-valid-formula-during-run-time